# Python flask docker port mapping on Heroku

Tags: docker, flask, heroku

I am trying to deploy a dockerized flask app into Heroku.

I am constantly getting "Port in use by another program" everytime I deploy. I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Please could someone help?

**DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ENV TZ=Pacific/Auckland
RUN echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["myapp.py"]
```

**myapp.py**

```
import os

import requests
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def parse_data():
    bla bla
    return result

port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn myapp:app
```

**LOGS FROM HEROKU**

```
2022-06-04T11:33:05.715431+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-04 11:33:05 +0000] [1560] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1560
2022-06-04T11:33:05.721157+00:00 app[web.1]: * Serving Flask app 'myapp' (lazy loading)
2022-06-04T11:33:05.721175+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2022-06-04T11:33:05.721202+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
2022-06-04T11:33:05.721219+00:00 app[web.1]: Use a production WSGI server instead.
2022-06-04T11:33:05.721232+00:00 app[web.1]: * Debug mode: on
2022-06-04T11:33:05.724607+00:00 app[web.1]: Address already in use
2022-06-04T11:33:05.724627+00:00 app[web.1]: Port 4050 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.
2022-06-04T11:33:05.724800+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-04 11:33:05 +0000] [1559] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1559)
```

The web page is rendered well from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing this line from the app:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

or place it in the usual `if` block, which ensures it only runs the development server when launched with the `python` executable instead of `gunicorn`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

The way you have this positioned just now, it looks like heroku is launching the server with `gunicorn` (correctly) but then the dev server launches with `app.run`afterwards, which causes the 'port in use error'.

The tell-tale sign is that you see the usual dev server warning in the logs, despite the `Procfile` (again correctly) launching the app with `gunicorn`.

Comment: Yes, this is just what it was. Fantastic catch. I wouldn't have ever picked this. Thanks a million to you for your timely help

Comment: @usert4jju7 Nice one, happy coding!